# Error resolving “nmcheck.gnome.org”: Name or service not known

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, gnome, connection

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I am able able to connect my laptop to all networks except my university wifi which requires authentication. Instead of the wifi login page, I get a page saying "Error resolving “nmcheck.gnome.org”: Name or service not known". I have tried all the solutions mentioned in this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/826998/cannot-log-in-to-public-open-wifi-connection and I also reinstalled gnome but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with docker. I stopped all running docker containers and deleted their images and then it worked fine.

Comment: I used `docker system prune` to fix mine, but I wonder if `docker network prune` might have been enough.

Comment: `docker network prune` worked for me

Comment: `docker network prune` is the key